# Is it possible to deserialize the results from an Azure Search?

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-cognitive-search

Calling Azure search from the REST API, the results are returned in a JSON-like structure.

```
{"@odata.context":"https://xxxx.search.windows.net/indexes('index-blob')/$metadata#docs(metadata_storage_size,metadata_storage_last_modified,metadata_storage_name,metadata_storage_path,metadata_content_type,metadata_title)","value":[{"@search.score":0.012103397,"metadata_storage_size":1479948,"metadata_storage_last_modified":"2017-04-17T18:31:18Z","metadata_storage_name":"90e975d1-3986-4167-87d2-4d1cdbc7be09.pdf","metadata_storage_path":"xxxx","metadata_content_type":"application/pdf","metadata_title":null},{"@search.score":0.004614377,"metadata_storage_size":116973,"metadata_storage_last_modified":"2017-04-13T18:24:01Z","metadata_storage_name":"xxx.pdf","metadata_storage_path":"xxxx","metadata_content_type":"application/pdf","metadata_title":"xxx"}]}
```

The trouble is I can't find a way to actually deserialize that. I can't figure out a structure that would deserialize "@search.score" (or similar parameters if the query is more complex). I've tried using various JSON->C# converters (including Edit->Paste Special in VS) but nothing really works. It seems odd I'd have to manually parse these results...I'm attributing it to something I don't understand about either Azure Search or JSON.

Comment: Can you use the `JsonProperty` attribute to solve this problem? http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm
eg. `[JsonProperty("@search.score")] public float SearchScore { get; set; }` - or am I not understanding your problem?

Comment: Thanks, that is perfectly acceptable! I was thinking there was some kind of structure or Azure Search param or some other way this had to work. JsonProperty works just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly and the problem lies with parsing JSON objects that have special characters in their key name, then you could try using `JsonProperty` attribute as such in you POCO (C# class to deserialize into):

```
public class AzureSearchResult {
    [JsonProperty("@search.score")]
    public float SearchScore { get; set;}
    //other variables...
}
```

For more information see http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Azure Search .NET SDK](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search), it will do the deserialization for you.